# Caminho dinâmico C#

Tags: c#

estou em busca de uma maneira de deixar o caminho de um arquivo dentro do meu projeto de forma dinâmica, atualmente esta assim:

```
string arquivoImagem = @"D:\Projetos\ProjetoSolution\Projeto.Web\Images\Gerenciador\login\logo.png";
```

Gostaria de não deixar este caminho fixo como esta acima, como faço para deixar ele dinâmico?

É uma aplicação web, este caminho é de uma imagem que vai ser inserida dentro de um report, é uma imagem da própria aplicação então não ha interferência do usuário, no caso o report utiliza o caminho para inserir a imagem no relatório que depois se torna um PDF. Queria uma forma de resolver isto pois temos problemas de quando outro desenvolvedor abre o projeto o caminho não existe, porque o projeto pode estar em outro local na maquina dele.

Comment: Isso em console ou Windwos form ?

Comment: Defina dinâmico. Oque você quer fazer? O que tem descrito não quer dizer nada, não sabemos como ajudar só com isto.

Comment: Você pode colocar para o usuario digitar o caminho

Comment: fiz algumas edições explicando melhor

Comment: Resolver o que? Diga o que precisa fazer. A questão aí é descobrir o que precisa, não está descrito na pergunta. Você quer colocar isto onde? Em um arquivo? Que tipo de arquivo? Um banco de dados? Uma variável global?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se chamado no contexto de uma chamada HTTP, utilize a seguinte função para obter o diretório-raiz da sua aplicação:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
```

Se você não possuir o contexto HTTP, ainda assim pode utilizar a segunte propriedade para obter o caminho da aplicação:

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
```

Fontes:
[HttpServerUtility.MapPath Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)
[HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Getting current directory in .NET web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951599/getting-current-directory-in-net-web-application)

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso você quer o caminho físico, que é um caminho a nível de sistema ("D:\blabla...").

Faça assim (usando [`HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath.aspx) ):

```
string arquivoImagem = $@"{HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath}\Images\Gerenciador\login\logo.png";
```

Answer (score 1):

Brayan, tive um problema parecido.
Criei uma tabela de configuração, nela contêm um ID para distinguir os arquivos e outro o path do arquivo. Depois é só concatenar as strings:

-- `dirParam` é a informação que está no banco de dados.

```
string dirParam = "..imagens\..\..";
string arquivoImagem = dirParam + "\logo.png";
```

O caso vai voltar 2 níveis na estrutura de pagina web e depois entrar na pasta imagens.

Espero que tenha ajudado.